# Get All Distinct Values From dataTable in vb

Tags: vb.net, linq

I need all distinct responses in list where Descriptor equals to TeamA

Here is Table

[image]

result would be [1 2]

Here is my Query It is working but iterates loop and put one by one but I need all at once

```
selectedDescValues = "TeamA"
filterExpression = "DescriptorValues='" & selectedDescValues & "'"
For Each responseResult In teamResponseResult.Select(filterExpression).Distinct
                                    distinctResAnswers.Add(responseResult("ResponseAnswers"))

 Next
```

please suggest

Comment: Do you want this in VB or C#?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should get you a distinct list of ResponseAns where the Descriptor is equal to "TeamA"

```
teamResponseResult.Where(x => x.Descriptor = "TeamA").Select(y => y.ResponseAns).Distinct()
```

Comment: your code is not working because this is not db this is datatable because in datatable we can not use .where